# Use array with MongooseArray.addToSet(...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would like to send an array to [MongooseArray.addToSet(...)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet) to update my mongoose model. But in the [mongoose API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet) it seems that the method only expects flat arguments

```
//myModel.mySet -> [1]
var addedToSet = myModel.mySet.addToSet(1,2,3);

//myModel.mySet -> [1,2,3]
//addedToSet  -> [2,3]
```

I would like the same functionality but using an array

```
//myModel.mySet -> [1]
var newToSet = [1,2,3]; //Array
var addedToSet = myModel.mySet.addToSet(newToSet);

//myModel.mySet -> [1,2,3]
//addedToSet  -> [2,3]
```

I tried using apply but I'm getting **undefined is not a function** error

```
var newToSet = [1,2,3];
var addedToSet = myModel.mySet.addToSet.apply(myModel, newToSet);
//undefined is not a function
```

Is there any API in mongoose that can do this I missed ?
or is there a different correct to this kind of update ?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should have just undeleted your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212645/send-an-array-to-mongoosearray-addtoset/) about this.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `apply` is the `this` context for the `addToSet` call, so it needs to be `myModel.mySet` instead.

```
var addedToSet = myModel.mySet.addToSet.apply(myModel.mySet, newToSet);
```